# Watson Assistant Webchat after deleting session the chat icon also disappears?

Tags: javascript, dom, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

New to javascript I am using the Watson assistant webchat framework(https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-events#windowclose) for web integration. I am able to update the CSS variables and other configurations but when I delete user sessions on minimizing the chatbot icon also disappears.

```
     window.watsonAssistantChatOptions = {   
          carbonTheme: 'g10',
          enableFocusTrap: true,
          onLoad: function(instance) {
          // Instance method to adjust specific CSS variables
          instance.updateCSSVariables({
            'BASE-font-family': '"Times New Roman", Times, serif',
            'BASE-width':'460px',
            'BASE-height':'500px',
            '$interactive-01': '#5dd7ec',
            '$interactive-03':'#002d9c',
            '$interactive-04':'#002d9c'
          });
      instance.openWindow();
      instance.writeableElements.headerBottomElement.innerHTML = ' &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Powered By <a href="https://teledental.com"><strong>TeleDental</strong></a>';
      instance.render();     
function handler(event)
 {
    instance.destroySession();
    instance.destroy();
    resolve();
  }
instance.on({ type: "window:close", handler: handler });  
    }
  };

            setTimeout(function(){
        const t=document.createElement('script');
        t.src="https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.appdomain.cloud/loadWatsonAssistantChat.js";
        document.head.appendChild(t);
      });
```

Comment: It is not clear: Are you asking a CSS question or anything related to Watson Assistant? What is the code before and after your changes?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish?

`instance.destroy()` will tear down the entire web chat and delete the launcher and all other UI elements related to the web chat. This is what is causing what you are seeing. (https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#destroy).

`instance.destroySession()` will remove all browser storage related to the web chat so if you want to, for instance, log the user out of your website, there is no identifying data left behind. (https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#destroySession)

I don't think you want to call either of these methods when someone simply closes the chat, they could just be looking at something else on the screen and want to come back to the chat, but perhaps I am missing what your end goal is here.

Comment: the end goal is to refresh the chatbot session(delete previous chat history) when the user closes the chat and when a user opens the chat again it should start from the beginning. In short when the user closes the chat it should render the chatbot Box and icon again but with no history.

Comment: just had to add window.location.reload() so that the widget could be rendered again.